# Multiple TestNG groups: can they be ANDed exclusively from the command line?

Tags: java, maven, command-line, testng

Let's assume I have a desktop UI and a mobile UI for the same back-end functionality (e.g. Account, Checkout). Then I would have the following test classes:

```
@Test(groups = { "desktop", "account" })
public class DesktopAccountTest {}

@Test(groups = { "desktop", "checkout" })
public class DesktopCheckoutTest {}

@Test(groups = { "mobile", "account" })
public class MobileAccountTest {}

@Test(groups = { "mobile", "checkout" })
public class MobileCheckoutTest {}
```

I will never need to run desktop and mobile tests in the same execution. On the other hand I would like to run all desktop tests, or all mobile tests, which is easy with `mvn test -Dgroups="desktop"` or `mvn test -Dgroups="mobile"`. But what if I just want to run desktop account tests for example? This doesn't work: `mvn test -Dgroups="desktop, account"`: it returns all desktop tests and all account tests.

Is there a way to get the intersection of the 2 groups, rather than their sum? From the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `mvn test -Dgroups="desktop,account"-DexcludedGtoups="mobile"`

But if you want to run only one test, it is also possible: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It provides additional filtering, but still based on the sum of the 2 groups, not their intersection. Anyway you still get my vote :)

Comment: True, but it is only what TestNG support inbox for the moment. You can easily make your own selection with [IMethodInterceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) where you will filter tests you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to create a [testng.xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) file, for each specific group.